# How do I start an Angular JS app in WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Usually I just type "npm start" to run an Angular JS app for testing. How do I set up a run configuration in WebStorm to do this? I don't see a way to run npm, or enter the "npm start" command from within the run configuration dialog. (Win 7 / Webstorm 9).

Comment: to start an app you hover over the index.html and select one of the browsers that it displays

Comment: In the left lower corner click terminal and run in it : npm start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use Node.js Run configuration for this:

```
Working dir: /path/to/your/package.json
JavaScript file: /path/to/global/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
Application parameters: run start
```